# hive-hwi-0.9.0.war is missing in Hive home directory

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I'm trying to run HWI (Hive Web Intervace).
Ss I understood, hive-hwi-0.9.0.war is required for HWI and is supposed to be in

```
$HIVE_HOME/lib.
```

When I check $HIVE_HOME/lib directory, there is no .war file there, only .jar files.

What did I miss?

Comment: Now I have checked Hadoop distribution of Hive and it has .war file in lib folder. Do you have URL from where You downloaded hive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dino.keco was right!

Standart Hive distribution has hive-hwi-0.9.0.war in ${HIVE_HOME}/lib
I just downloaded Hive distribution again and copied hive-hwi-0.9.0.war to my local Hive installation.